# how fragment can get data from parentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities `MainActivity` and `DetailActivity`, if I click in the ListView in `MainActivity` will intent to `DetailActivity` with content "id", in `DetailActivity` I have 2 fragment (TabLayout-ViewPager).

My question is: How can fragment get "id" from that intent above???

Comment: `getActivity().getIntent()`? But you probably should pass the intent's data "down" to the Fragment, rather than "reach up" for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Fragment in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)
,If Android decides to recreate your Fragment later, it's going to call the no-argument constructor of your fragment. So overloading the constructor is not a solution.[for more detail please read this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/3678308)

```
private int mId;
private static final String ID = "id";
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int id) {
    DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ID, id);

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

get values in oncreate method

@Override

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null)
//mId is variable which contain (YourActivity)MainActivity value.you can use in fragment.
                mId = getArguments().getInt(ID);


        }
```

//call in your YourActivity(MainActivity) in oncreate method

```
 int id = yourid;
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,DetailFragment.newInstance(id)).commit();
```

Comment: good answer, but a bit more descriptive text to explain your answer should help get your answer accepted

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

from [Android Developer's Fragment Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

```
DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

// Supply index input as an argument.
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("index", index);
f.setArguments(args);

// add fragment to the fragment manager's stack
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @cricket_007 says, create a factory method in your fragment and pass the data through bundle arguments consider the example below

```
public static YourFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
      Yourfragment fragment = new YourFragment();
      Bundle bundle = args;
      // Or if your args is a variable data for example a string
      // use Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putString("extra_name",value);
        // Now set the fragment arguments
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
     return fragment;
}
```

And now anywhere in your fragment you can do

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
// and access your extra by args.getString("extra_name"); ...
```